# Creating first Django project using jython

Tags: django, jython

I am trying to create my 1st project in django using jython. I am following this tutorial - http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/.

As mentioned in tutorial, I navigate to the directory where i intend to create a django project and run 'jython C:\jython2.5.1\Lib\site-packages\django\bin\django-admin.py'. On pressing enter, it says- Type 'django-admin.py help' for usage.
 It is not creating a new project. I am using windows and have installed jython 2.5.1 and django 1.1.1.
I tried searching on google but no luck. This is the very first step and i am not getting how to do it. please help.

Comment: got it.. was doing it all wrong!!

Comment: the right syntax is django_admin.py startproject some_project_name ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to type `django_admin.py startproject your_project`, where `your_project` is whatever you want to call your project.